# Using Passwords to Navigate Screens

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-router, password-protection

I am doing a react native + firebase app. At the moment, I am struggling to make a message pop up asking for a certain password whenever I press one of the page routers. I have 3 pages nested in an StackNavigator at `App.js`.

As you can see on the following code, I have 3 routers to those pages (which are `HelderScreen.js`, `LolsScreen.js` and `AthleanScreen.js`). Whenever I click on these routers, I want a message pop up to ask for a unique password to each of those routers.

This is my `Home.js` main code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation, Image, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView style={styles.flatlist}>
      <View style={styles.flatlist1}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Helder')}>
          <Text style={styles.item}>Empresa do Helder</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.flatlist1}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Lols')}>
          <Text style={styles.item}>Lols Inc</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.flatlist1}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Athlean')}>
          <Text style={styles.item}>Tesla Portugal</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>          
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

And this is the main code from my `App.js`, which has the StackNavigator and the BottomStackNavigator

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
screen: HomeScreen,
navigationOptions: () => ({
    headerShown: false
})
  },
  Helder: {
screen: HelderScreen,
navigationOptions: () => ({
  title: "Helder"
})
  },
  Athlean: {
screen: AthleanScreen,
navigationOptions: () => ({
  title: "Athlean"
})
  },
  Lols : {
screen: LolsScreen,
navigationOptions: () => ({
  title: "Lols"
})
  }
});


const AppContainer = createBottomTabNavigator (
  {
        Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-home' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },
    Message: {
      screen: MessageScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-chatboxes' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },      
    Notification: {
      screen: NotificationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-notifications' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: DrawerNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-person' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions:{
      tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
        if (navigation.state.key === 'Post'){
          navigation.navigate('postModal')
        } else {
          defaultHandler()
        }
      }
    },

    tabBarOptions:{
      activeTintColor: 'orange',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black',
      showLabel: false
    }
  },
 {
mode: 'modal',
headerMode: 'none'
  }
)
```

I am new to React Native, could you please help me?

Comment: You need to create a custom component to achieve this scenario. For example, you can wrap 2 TextInput's and a Button inside a Modal and control the flow on passwords match.  Please explore https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

Comment: Hi Thiago its me again I helped you yesterday :D -  I guess a Modal is a goot solution and you could call it on componentDidMount or something so the second you enter the screen it should appear.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Solved it with some help!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `react-native-modal` in order to achieve this behavior. What you have to do is,

1) Create a Modal which contains a `TextInput` to type password and a Submit button.

2) Once the user clicked on the button in the `Home.js` screen, the `Modal` should be opened and ask for the password. (Please make sure that you have a `ref` to the modal and you have implemented necessary things to open the modal on button press using `ref`.

3) When the user entered the password, you can authenticate and then navigate to the screen you want if it is authenticated. (You can write the code for authentication and navigation inside your `Modal` implementation `js` file.)

Here is a sample code...

`PasswordInputModal.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

export default class PasswordInputModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      password  : '',
      isVisible : false,
      navigateTo: null,
    };
  }

  open = (navigateTo) => this.setState({ isVisible: true, navigateTo: navigateTo });

  close = () => this.setState({ isVisible: false });

  onPressSubmitButton = () => {
    //Use any authentication method you want according to your requirement.
    //Here, it is taken as authenticated if and only if the input password is "12345".

    const isAuthenticated = ("12345" == this.state.password); //If input password is '12345', isAuthenticated gets true boolean value and false otherwise.

    if(isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate(this.state.navigateTo);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Invalid password"); //Prompt an error alert or whatever you prefer.
    }

    this.close();
  }

  renderModalContent = () => (
    <View>
      <TextInput type={'password'} value={this.state.password} onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })} />
      <Button onPress={() => this.onPressSubmitButton()} title="Submit" color="#841584" />
    </View>
  );


  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
        backdropColor="#000000"
        backdropOpacity={0.9}
        animationIn="zoomInDown"
        animationOut="zoomOutUp"
        animationInTiming={600}
        animationOutTiming={600}
        backdropTransitionInTiming={600}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={600}
      >
        {this.renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

`Home.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import PasswordInputModal from './PasswordInputModal.js'

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.flatlist}>
          <View style={styles.flatlist1}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.PasswordInputModal.open('Helder')}>
              <Text style={styles.item}>Empresa do Helder</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.flatlist1}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.PasswordInputModal.open('Lols')}>
              <Text style={styles.item}>Lols Inc</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.flatlist1}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.PasswordInputModal.open('Athlean')}>
              <Text style={styles.item}>Tesla Portugal</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>          
        </ScrollView>

        <PasswordInputModal
          ref={modal => this.PasswordInputModal = modal} 
          navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When opening the modal, I've passed the name of the screen which you want to navigate after successful authentication. That screen name is passed as an argument of the `open()` function and, a state is set for using when to navigate.

I didn't test this code and the styles of the modal are not applied by me. Please go through this and try to do it as you want. Feel free to ask me if you have any problems. Good luck!

Comment: Hey! thanks for the effort to solve my problem! I really apreciate it and I am glad that there are people like you in this world :). I tried typing the code and adapted it to my whole app but there is an error on "onPressLearnMore", it cand find the variable. Where is the variable even used?

Comment: Plus, whenever I type on the textbox it delivers the error Invariant Violation:: setState(..):

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation! :-) Oh, I'm sorry, I've made two mistakes there. `onPressLearnMore` should be replaced with `onPressSubmitButton`. The problem for the error `invarient violation...` is, I made a mistake when passing the values into `setState`. The curly braces were missed. I've fixed those two issues. You can try it and pleaselet me know if you have any further question. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Whenever I click on Submit it still give the error "Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate'). Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Yeah... I've forgotten to pass `navigation` as a `prop` to the `Modal`. So, the modal doesn't know what this navigation prop is. Simply, it's undefined in this case. That's why you got the above error. I've updated the code in `Home.js`. Please check it and let me know. :-)

Comment: Ok, I understood it very well! Just 2 last things: one of them is the error "Can't find variable: close" which is the prop that suposely closes the Modal; and last one is that whatever that Password I type in and press submit, it still navigates to the screen indicated. I changed the password on the constructor(props) to '123456' and still, by typing nothing, it still navigates.

Comment: Good!  The reason for "Can't find variable: close" is, I've forgotten to call it with `this`. When we using `classes`, we must call a function or use a variable by referencing the current component scope. That's why we have to put `this` keyword in front of them. Without that, it doesn't know where that function or variable is defined. I've updated the code!

Comment: You have to authenticate before you navigate to the screen. my friend. That's why I commented on it. You should check if the entered password is matching with the authentic password. Only if they matched, then you should navigate. Otherwise, just prompt an error alert or whatever you prefer.

Comment: You are welcome! :-) I'm so glad to hear that you learned a lot from this..!! :-) Good luck!! :-)

Comment: Just one more thingy! Whenever the user logs into one of those pages I don't want him to be able to go back to Home.js as simple as pressing "Go Back" from our phones default button. Is there a function or props to do so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214993/discussion-between-sennen-randika-and-tiago-2-0).